# EF 4 Data Not Refreshing Windows Service

Tags: entity-framework, windows-services

I am running a windows service and it uses EF 4 for its datasource.  I use a field as a flag in the database, but when I see the field within the program it is null.  I think the issue is that the data must be cached, but at the same time I see the query being run in SQL Profiler (which returns the correct value, not null).  Fo course if the data is being cached it makes me wonder why the database is being called at all.  So any help would be appreciated.

Wade

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to debug your problem with so little information. What's the relevant EF model? What's your test code?

Comment: Look, I am just trying to see if there is a known problem with EF and windows services.  I noticed odd behavior and I am not sure if anyone has seen it before. I am not sure how code will help since I believe this is a problem with my usage.  This is not an issue when I run this code in isolation, so my testing never found the issue.